# Traversing DOM to second generation children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a neater to do this:

`(this.firstChild.firstChild).click();`

It seems like nth-child selectors must be on a jQuery element and "this" here is not.  Here's the whole function.

```
function toggleExpandAll() {
    $.each(($("#mainTbl>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)").slice(0,50)), function(){
        (this.firstChild.firstChild).click();
        openItems(this.firstChild.firstChild.id, true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Well being that you're using a strange combination of jQuery and pure JS, there is certainly a better way. However, without your HTML markup, it's unclear if that better way has to rely on the "first child of first child" or can make use of a more direct selector. Perhaps you can edit your question to include the corresponding HTML and we can suggest you a cleaner method/selector.

Comment: I agree with @Santi, if you use some kind of class for it then you could do `$(this).find('.my-class:first').click();`. It would be slightly less cumbersome and more agile. With firstChild who knows what could get inserted into the html to throw it off.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Thanks. I think the question suffers from being both too specific (asking about one single line of code) *and* being too broad (not enough information provided). OP, I feel like if you instead added your HTML and explained what you're trying to accomplish, we can clean up the entire process rather than just one single line.